# c# get list of users that have a specific foreign key

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have a many to many relationship between Users and Roles as a user can have many roles and a role can be associated to many users.

As role titles I have guest (id 1) and normalUser(id 2)

I am trying to get all the normalUser that there are in the database but I do not want the guests because i have to set permissions as required

this is my code so far

```
    public List<User> GetnormalUsers()
    {
        return Entity.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Contains(2).ToList());
    }
```

this is giving me an error stating that I cannot convert from 'int' to 'Common.Role'.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

From the given partial data I would try

```
return Entity.Users.Where(user => user.Roles.Any(role => role.Id == 2)).ToList();
```

Two problems where in your statement:

1. You simply had the closing bracket for the `.ToList()` statement on the wrong position, materializing the wrong collection.
2. `.Contains()` doesn't work that way. Instead you have to use `.Any()`.

Comment: Explain what he did wrong so he might understand his mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Two things: you need to access the Id (presumably) property of Roles in order for your filter to work, and your .ToList() is in the wrong position.

```
public List<User> GetnormalUsers()
{
        return Entity.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.Id == 2)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @jAC, thanks for the correction, I've fixed it. I initially zeroed in on the ToList in the wrong position and didn't catch that they were not using the property accessor.